# Make eclipse editor only accessible from another editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have the following two editors (as two seperate plugins):

(1) textual editor
(2) graphical editor to edit information related to the content in (1)

Now I would like to achieve that editor (2) can only be opened from a context menu in editor (1). That means, editor (2) should not appear in the "open with" context menu when clicking on a file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editors only appear in the `Open With` context menu if they are associated with a file content type in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point which defines the editor. The association is done either by specifying the `extensions` attribute or using a `contentTypeBinding`.

So if you don't specify a content type association the editor can only be open programmatically and won't appear in `Open With`.

Comment: But in this case the editor would still show up if the user pressed "Other...", wouldn't it?